# How can i get the image to 100% of screen without resizing or scaling

Tags: html, css, image

Here i have the .png image in img, when i reduce the window size of browser, the image is still appearing in original style and scroller is appearing at the bottom of the page. but i want the original image with no scroller on bottom. and i don't want to scale or resize the image.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/custom.css" type="text/css" />
<title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
        <img src="assets/images/background.png" class="headerimg">\
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.headerimg{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

This is how its appearing now. you can see the scroller at the bottom, and when i scroll, the image appears with actual width.but when i resize the window the original size of the image should remain same but it should appear fit in the screen without scroller.max-width:100%; scales up the image, but it should not scale up the image instead the image height and width should remain as it is and scroller should not appear at bottom.

How can i do this with css?

[image]

Comment: Please, post your completed code or provide a demo. You have to give `max-width:100%;` to `img`

Comment: you can add width:100% in your headerimg class.

Comment: Provide a jsFiddle link pls.

Comment: OK, i fixed it by adding the overflow-x: hidden to the parent element...

Comment: Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7romu7m4/)

Answer (score 1):

```
.headerimg{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    width: [image's real width];
}
```

For scrollbar i need more code to see, but i can say you can use "overflow: hidden" in the outer div/body.

Answer (score 0):

You could try applying a background image to the body element like so...

```
body {
  background-image: url('../images/background.png');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

If you need to attach it to an element you could create a section or div element with a class of headerimg and apply the following...

```
.headerimg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-image: url('../images/background.png');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

I hope this helps.